# Reactjs : Return function result to webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I created a function called `belowEighteen()` which return the number of documents from a firestore with res.size(). I want to display the returned value to the webpage by calling the function using `{belowEighteen()}`, but it's not displaying anything onto the webpage.

The console however, returns the value that I want. I just need it to be displayed to the screen now

Here's the code for `belowEighteen()` function:

```
belowEighteen (){
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('answers')
        .where('age', '==', 'Less than 18')
        .get()
        .then((res) => { 
            // Display total number to console 
            console.log(res.size);
            return (res.size);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Error getting documents: ${error}`);
            //to_return = " ";
        });

    }
```

Here's the code that I used to call the function in my `render()`:

```
<li>Less than 18 (Total: {this.belowEighteen()} )</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the value within a promise function, so that won't return directly from the `belowEighteen` function, rather it will return from the promise function. An option would be to use the React state.

Define the state variable in the constructor:

```js
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    total: 0
  }
}
```

Adjust the function and UI to use the state variable:

```js
belowEighteen () {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection('answers')
  .where('age', '==', 'Less than 18')
  .get()
  .then((res) => { 
      // Display total number to console 
      console.log(res.size);
      this.setState({
        total: res.size
      })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log(`Error getting documents: ${error}`);
      //to_return = " ";
  });
}
```

```
<li>Less than 18 (Total: {this.state.total} )</li>
```

Comment: but it's not updating the state when I update the size though..

Comment: yes but it remains 0 when i use your code. this line ```<li>Less than 18 (Total: {this.state.total} )</li>``` does show up on my UI though

Comment: You're using a "get data once" function https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data - you are only retrieving the value once as intended. This is for a separate question, though.

Comment: What does it mean? i still don't get it.. pardon me i'm very new to reactjs

Comment: You're misunderstanding Firebase, not React. Your query is not realtime; you can only get the value once per function call. Look at the API link I gave you previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206758/discussion-between-spjy-and-falady).